# How do I tell my PHP Include to source images from my root?

Tags: php, html

**Let me re-explain my problem.**

My header is stored in `header.php`, I'm using `<?php include('/header.php');?>` to grab it. This works fine on all web pages in my root.

But, I have a folder called Catalogue in my root with more web pages, so then I change it to `<?php include('../header.php'); ?>` which again works fine.

however, I am sourcing a few images in my `header.php`. The images do not appear on web pages in my catalogue folder, because I am sourcing them from the images folder in my root `<img src="images/cosworth2.jpg">`

I can't use `<img src="../images/cosworth2.jpg"` because this will then affect the images that work fine on the web pages that aren't in my catalogue folder.

Does this make sense?

I need to tell my `header.php` to source all of my images from the root even if my web pages are in other directories.

**Header.php**

```
<div id="top"><center><img src="images/header.png" style="max-width:100%;"></center></div>
<header id="header" class="site-header" role="banner">
<div id="header-inner" class="container sixteen columns over">
<hgroup class="one-third column alpha">

</hgroup>
    <nav id="main-nav" class="two thirds column omega">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about-us.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="news.php">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="dealers.php">Dealers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="products.php">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/shop">Buy Online</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contactus.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>

<div class="container"><img src="images/cosworth2.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto; float:left; margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px;">
<p style="padding-top:25px;">Welcome to <strong>Cosworth Europe</strong>. This website is specifically for Cosworth Aftermarket & Performance Products. For any other enquires please visit Cosworth.com. For more information, feel free to visit the About Us page.</p></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Change the path to the images in your web pages to use the same resource. Duplication shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: You could use `include("../header.php")` for accessing from a subfolder. `../` just navigates the include to the parent directory, so you can use them to get "up"

Comment: But the majority of my web pages are in the root, so using ../ will then mess up the images on my main page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an absolute path.

```
<img src="/images/..." alt="...">
```

Describe the location of your images (and stylesheets, etc) relative to the root of the website.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, an absolute path uses the URL? correct? > '<img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/img3.jpg"'

Comment: @s.poole — You could use an absolute URL if you like, but that makes this awkward for dealing with dev/staging/live environments. An absolute path is a relative URL that just includes the path (and optionally query and fragment) parts … but the *whole* path starting from `/` … like the example I put in the answer in the first place.

Comment: I've re-explained my problem. I don't think I explained properly.

Comment: @s.poole — The edits to the question don't change my answer at all.

Comment: well can you explain your answer please? You have to appreciate that people are new to this and won't have the knowledge that you do, I'm confused by your answer and can't see how it works. Thanks

Comment: @s.poole — I gave an example in the answer. I explained in in the first comment I made in this thread. There's not really anything else to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96883/discussion-between-s-poole-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

To add to others answers, you could [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) a PHP Constant for the purpose of setting the absolute path. This would help if you ever had to change the directory/path.

```
//perhaps add this in a config file or at the top of the header.php file
define( 'IMAGE_PATH', '/images' );

//use in any other file
<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH; ?>/image1.png" />
```

Comment: I've re-explained my problem. I don't think I explained properly.